# SWF behaves strangely when it is embeded in HTML

Tags: flash-cs4, flash

I have a SWF file and I am trying to embed it into an HTML.

I used the following code:

```
    <object width="704" height="440">
    <param name="movie" value="http://riskgames.ist.psu.edu/CyberLinkIT.swf"></param>
    <embed src="http://riskgames.ist.psu.edu/CyberLinkIT.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" menu="false" width="704" height="440">
    </embed>
    </object>
```

If you go to http://miaojiang.net/bug.html, you can see the problem. The button is blinking and all invisible text field are displayed.

However, if I open the swf file directly, there is no problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem.

SecurityError: Error #2149: Security sandbox violation: https://riskgames.ist.psu.edu/CyberLinkIT.swf cannot make fscommand calls to http://miaojiang.net/bug.html (allowScriptAccess is ).
    at FSCommand$/_fscommand()
    at global/flash.system::fscommand()
    at CyberLinkIT_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

```
<object width="704" height="440">
        <param name="movie" value="http://riskgames.ist.psu.edu/CyberLinkIT.swf"></param>
        <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://riskgames.ist.psu.edu/CyberLinkIT.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" menu="false" width="704" height="440" AllowScriptAccess="always">
        </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: The sandbox violation is occuring because you are hosting the html on one domain, and the swf on another.  You could move them both to the same domain, and that should fix it.  Or if you are using as3 you can try adding Security.allowDomain("*"); to your code, you can also look into adding a crossdomain file which I don't think fscommand uses....  Since you are using fscommand I'm thinking you're using as2 ?

Comment: The swf is developed by my colleagues and I believe they are using as3. I am not sure what they are doing with fscommand. You are right, I am trying to embed the swf from a different domain. I will first try if Security.allowDomain("*") solves the problem.

Comment: I have added Security.allowDomain("*"); and it did not solve the problem. Given the fact that I cannot move the html and swf into the same domain, is there any other way to solve the problem? THanks.

Comment: Why can't you move the swf to the domain the html is on?  You obviously have access to the html, so you can save the swf to your computer, and upload it to where your html is, and change the path to the swf.

Comment: try adding <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"> to your embed

Comment: I have updated my post with the allowscriptaccess code, change it to that

Comment: I have added that AllowScriptAccess and it still does not work. Yes, I can move the swf to the same domain. However, we want to allow external websites to embed this swf just like YouTube. So I want to make sure this works. :-)

Comment: Did you use the code example I provided? You have to add it to the embed tag as well as the param for the object tag.  I created a html page on my own domain using this code and it worked fine.  Please try copy / pasting the code I provided.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem solved. I did not add it to the embed tag.